# cannot import name 'save_virtual_workbook' from 'openpyxl.writer.excel'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there an update to the library?

Before it worked perfectly, and today I updated and it no longer loads

I searched but I can't find any other option

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Without source code and a clear error message, it's impossible to answer your question. Please see [ask], then [edit] your question and add your code, as text, formatted (use the `{}` button), as a [mcve].

Comment: Although not mentioned in the [release notes](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/changes.html#id1), it seems that version 3.1.0 (released today) [removed it](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/api/openpyxl.writer.excel.html)...

Comment: This was deprecated a long time ago and was also removed from the documentation.

Comment: *save_virtual_workbook* is a deprecated in openpyxl. Last version openpyxl with this function 3.0.10. [code](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/3.0.10/openpyxl/writer/excel.py#L297)

Comment: seems we now need to save a temp file, then open it and get the buffer back into RAM? Seems wasteful...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the new recommendation from the developers is to use a temp-file:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/tutorial.html?highlight=save#saving-as-a-stream

**update:** I ended up having to use this with modifications

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    tmp.close() # with statement opened tmp, close it so wb.save can open it
    wb.save(tmp.name)
    with open(tmp.name, 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(0) # probably not needed anymore
        new_file_object = f.read()
```

because the `with` statement opens the file and then `wb.save` (which expects a `string` *filename*) attempts to open it, resulting in an `Exception`

Answer (score 5):

The official recommendation does not work (as-is) on Windows + it uses the filesystem to save the workbook, even if only briefly.

Here a better method in my mind which is all in-memory:

```
with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    wb.save(buffer)
    content = buffer.getvalue()
```

This works because the underlying `ZipFile()` used [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/writer/excel.py#L291) accepts a file-like object in addition to filename.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this issue by installing an older version 3.0.10
`pip install openpyxl==3.0.10`